# C++ how to fix void* arithmethic in old code

Tags: c++

I have some old code I inherited that I am maintaining and want to change as little as possible. It does not compile with newer compilers.

There is more to the code but basically the idea, I think, (regardless how bad) is to pass a void* to the start of a table of records of arbitrary record size. I do not want to make changes outside of this function since it gets ugly. I think I just want to cast to an unsigned char* and do the addition and then cast back to void* but I am having trouble figuring out the right casting etc.

Any suggestions?

Here is the original code:

```
foo(const void* recordArrayBasePtr ,ubin32 sizeOfStruct)
{
   void * recordPtr;
   int row = 9; //for example
   recordPtr = const_cast<void *>( recordArrayBasePtr ) + sizeOfStruct * row;
}
```

Comment: You want const_cast< void* > as you have in your example, and reinterpret_cast< char* >. This is not enough, though, for your function's declaration is not having returned type, and there is no return at the end of your function. There is definitively something missing here.

Comment: Why are you tagging this *C++*? Isn't this plain *C*?

Comment: This is C++ written by a C programmer. The solution from @jon did the trick: reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<void *>( recordArrayBasePtr )) + sizeOfStruct * row;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cast to `char*`, which is done with `reinterpret_cast` and not with `const_cast`. But considering that this is really C code, you can just as well use C-style casts which will be less of a hassle to write:

```
 recordPtr = (void*)((char*)recordArrayBasePtr + sizeofStruct * row);
```

Comment: recordPtr = static_cast<void *>( reinterpret_cast<char*>(recordArrayBasePtr) + m_haipeTableArray[tableId].sizeOfStruct * row);  //this does not compile -- error: reinterpret_cast from type 'const void*' to type 'char*' casts away constness

Comment: @joemooney: You need both casts there. But frankly I 'd use a C-style cast here. There's no point in putting nice C++ varnish over what is C code.

Comment: Any chance of putting that in C++ style casting for me? The compile will issue wanrings and I need to avoid warnings about old C style casts.

Comment: @joemooney: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<void *>( recordArrayBasePtr )) + sizeOfStruct * row;` Although I 'm not sure why you need to cast away the constness.

Comment: Excellent! That worked. I needed to cast away the constness because the pointer is passed down into another can of worms.

Comment: `static_cast` to from `void*` is legal (or `const void *`).